# What's the name of the lemma $a_n \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} a \Rightarrow a_{n-1} \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} a$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Is there a name for this?

$$a_n \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} a~~, ~~~~~
b_n := a_{n-1} \\
\;
\\
 \Rightarrow ~~~b_n \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} a$$

I need this to justify

$$\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )^{n} \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} e ~~~~~ \Rightarrow ~~~~~ \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n-1} \right )^{n-1} \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} e$$

Comment: It's a case of more general theorem on subsequences. If $a_{n}\to L$ and $k_{n} $ is a sequence of positive integers such that $k_{n} \to\infty$ then $a_{k_{n}} \to L$. Your case is $k_{n} =n-1$. It is an immediate consequence of the definition of limit of a sequence.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, but does this have a name? What would you write down when you're supposed to justify the step?

Comment: Not every result has a name. And this particular  result is more or less a trivial application of definition of limit. It should be considered part of common knowledge which can be used when dealing with limit of sequences. If you wish to be explicit, you may just mention the result in a single sentence as "if a sequence converges to some value then all its subsequences also converge to the same value".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this fact has a name, since it's usually used without proof. Here's how to prove it using the definition of the limit:

Assume $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$. Then for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N \in \Bbb N$ such that for all $k \geq N$ we have $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$. Now consider $C = N+1$. For all $k \geq C$, we have $|a_{k-1} - a| < \epsilon$, since $k-1 \geq N$. Thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n-1} = a$.